# linear matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove the equation below:

$(A^TA + \mu I)^{-1}A^T$  =  $A^T(AA^T +  \mu I)^{-1}$

no ideas at all, i major in signal processing and it needs some math techniques so i am not familiar with this part of knowledge, really need help please.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the equation out into two terms?  For example, $(A+B)C = AC + BC$.

Comment: Needn't he use the inverse law first

Comment: At least we know that $(A^TA + \mu I)^{-1}$ is symmetric.

Comment: It is very simple! Left multiply by $(A^TA + \mu I)$, then right multiply by $(AA^T +  \mu I)$, you end up with $A^T(AA^T +  \mu I)=(AA^T +  \mu I)A^T$ which is evidently true by development of LHS and RHS.